# check data value in d3js parse csv

Tags: d3.js

i'm parsing a csv file and i need to check a particular data value and do something else do something else... but for me in the below script the value shown in undefined. i wanto fetch the data and check the same: data.source should have fetched the data right? and usingthe normal javascript checking i should have been able to check the value. currently not working... how to implement the same

```
     var canvas = d3.select("body").selectAll("#viz").append("svg")

d3.csv("INPUT.csv", function(data) 
{

    data.forEach(function(d)
    {
        var x = d.source; 
        if(x==='NA')
        {
            alert(x);

             var visual = canvas.selectAll("circle")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append("svg:circle")
                    .attr("cx",20)
                    .attr("cy",10)
                    .attr("r",15)
                    .style("fill","lightgreen")

        }
        else
        {

            var rectangle = canvas.selectAll("rect")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("svg:rect")
            .attr("x", 10)
            .attr("y", 10)
            .attr("width", 50)
            .attr("height", 100);
        }

     });

});
```

The alert is showing the correct data but an svg image is not created accordingly

Comment: Did you verify that the data is loaded correctly?

Comment: yes it has  loaded with the parsecsv i had written these and its working  var visual = canvas.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("svg:circle")
  .attr("cx",20)
  .attr("cy",10)
  .attr("r",15)
  .style("fill",function(d)
   {
    var fcolor ="lightgrey";
    if(d.source =="Mutation")
    {
     fcolor ="lightskyblue";

    }
     return fcolor;
   }
   )

Comment: i had edited my question .. in fact i had found way to check values but on this condition i have to create an svg.. but its not happening.

Comment: What is not happening?

Comment: I need to draw a rectangle if x!=="NA. Every time it draws a circle. even though an alert statement shows the value other than "NA"

Comment: You would need to pass `d` to `.data()`, not `data`. And a custom matching function -- something like `.data(d, function(d) { return d; })`.

Comment: teh circle size and positions changes as per the csv data so if i provide .data(d, function(d) { return d; }) it dosent draw the circles/rectangles

Comment: It sounds like you want to prefilter you data to have separate arrays for circles and rectangles. Then you can use the usual way of creating elements in D3.